# Symfony & Easyadmin : how to display several entity list on the same page

Tags: list, symfony, easyadmin

I try to display several entity lists on the same page under symfony & easyadmin.

I then created a route link in the menu which calls a controller to display a custom template.

In this template, I tried to use

```
{{ render(url(path('easyadmin', { entity: firstechild, action: 'list' }))) }}
```

and

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AdminController::indexAction',
        { 'entity':  firstechild, 'action': 'list'}))}}
```

but none works.